# Reference for Atkin-Lehner theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

For my understanding of modular forms, I have "properly" read the last chapter of Serre's book on arithmetic. I have not "properly" read the setup of Hecke operators for congruence subgroups.

I was intending to read the paper of Atkin and Lehner for filling this lacuna, as well as for understanding the proof of Atkin-Lehnher theorem. For some reason I could not relate very well with the exposition in the book of Diamond & Shurman or the book of Shimura.

I would be most grateful if somebody can point out some good reference for the Atkin-Lehner theorem other than these.

Comment: The Atkin-Lehner paper is quite readable.

Comment: Dear Denham, if Robin's comment above was a good answer, will you please re add it as an answer and accept it, to provide closure to this question? Otherwise it'll stay unanswered indefinitely...

Answer (score 1):

[This book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=GtEwY53Nx7wC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=Atkin%E2%80%93Lehner%20theory&source=bl&ots=QtasnBWOVY&sig=sqwX5G9cUNkejkoqyZSkSriUmHw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F0jeT5PfKuaL6gHospy8Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Atkin%E2%80%93Lehner%20theory&f=false) by Lang has an exposition on the Atkin-Lehner theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at page 82 of the [following notes](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~kani/lectures/m817w05/modforms.pdf).